# Centering lopsided content

Tags: html, css

Im trying to evenly center some content on a page. Here is an example of what I have done so far: [Codepen RTC](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/iftJA/)

How can I make the "hello" in the center of the page? I don't mind if the "some text before. sesquipedalian" gets pushed out of view.

Thanks

EDIT: [Mockup of what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZIsh.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/scfxy/

Absolute position to spans. If you want to get rid of them then add `top: -50px;`

Comment: Sorry, not quite what i'm looking for. I have updated the post with what I want :)

Comment: In that case it's little bit trickier and it has to be done via javascript.

Comment: Ok, damn. I was hoping it could be done in css. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: No, in CSS it's definitely not possible :)